# manage recurring events in a schedule C

Tags: c, embedded

--UPDATE--

ok this is what I have figured out so far.

for an event that is supposed to run say on a bi weekly basis this is what I have done.

1. convert Schedule timestamp and Current Timestamp to a unix time
2. (schduleTime - currentTime) % 14 // 14 because there are 14 days in 2 weeks it could be any number
3. this will tell me if today is two weeks from the last time the event was run.

for and event that is supposed to run every x number of months or years

There are some other checks to perform before getting to the actual calculation

like making sure that the sch time is right now ... etc

1. make sure that today is the same date as the one in the sch
2. once the date is the correct one then "(ScheduelMonth - currentMonth) % 2" lets say it is supposed to run every 2 months

now a simple example

start time stamp of an event 2010 - 11 - 23  every 3 months

now lets pretend that todays date is 2011 - 02 - 23

then the calculations will look like this.

if( Sch_Date == Current_Data ) // if( 23 == 23 )

if( !((Sch_Month - Current_Month) % 3) ) // if( !( (11-2)%3 ) // which equals zero

I hope this makes sense let me know if I am missing something

1.

Hi,

I am programming an STM32 micro and I need to create a scheduling engine that will allow the user to schedule tasks to happen at given times and intervals.

I have an RTC that will provide me with the current time stamp. The part where I am getting stuck is how to deal with the recurring events.

ie.

if the user wants something to run every Friday but weekly, bi-weekly, monthly or yearly.

the user provides me with a start and end times and a recurring flag which tells me what days he wants this to run and how often.

I hope I made this clear enough.

If you have any ideas and/or questions it would be appreciated

Update

This is my specific problem.

I have the device checking every so often to see if any of the schedule entries its supposed to start. I think the best way to describe it its by example

user sends this event

start time 
2010 11 09 TUE 16 30 00

end time 
2012 11 09

recuring flags every tuesday bi weekly

I can check if the event its ready to start but how do I deal with the fact that its only supposed to happen every two weeks I need some help coding the algorithm to deal with the recursion

Comment: Did you mean recurring instead of recursion ?

Comment: yes, sorry that is just what we call those flags but recurring makes it more understandable its fixed

Comment: This is quite a broad question.  What are the specific problems that you're encountering?  e.g. Designing the interface?  Designing the algorithm?  Coding the algorithm?  Using the RTC?

Comment: Maybe something based on [cron format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Examples)?

Comment: @pmg: No evidence so far that he's running *nix, or even an OS at all.  He probably is, though.  If so, then yes, he should use existing tools.

Comment: this is in an 32bit micro controller im using C so cron is not an option

Comment: I didn't mean a real cron ... just the format. For your needs you could, perhaps, take the cron format and add a week column: `30 16 * * 4 */2` (every other thursday at 16:30)

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you've described as your specific problem:

For each new entry, calculate and record the timestamp of the *first* time the event needs to trigger (e.g. `2010-11-09_16:30`).  When an event triggers, calculate the timestamp for the *next* time the event needs to trigger based on the flags (e.g. `2010-11-23_16:30`), and replace the record.

Note that it's probably best to translate all timestamps to something standard, like [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: yes that was one of first ideas was to keep taking a timestamp of the next event but I was reminded by my boss that We need to keep the original schedule in EE prom memory so also not an option

Comment: @jramirez: Ok, well store both.  Or store the updates in RAM.

Comment: @Jramirez: If your rules are simple enough (e.g. daily, weekly, etc.), then you can avoid storage, and simply calculate the next event by dividing `(now - first_timestamp)` by the time-interval.  For more complicated rules where the intervals are not regular (e.g. bi-weekly, or monthly), then this approach would be more tricky.

Comment: @jramirez: the "rules" are stored in EEPROM, in a suitable format. What Oli Charlesworth is describing is calculated from the rules, and stored in RAM.

Comment: @Craig I understand. I was talking to a collegue of mine and he mentioned successive approximation are any of you familiar with that ??

Comment: That terminology isn't familiar to me.

Comment: @jramirez: Successive approximation is usually used in the context of analogue-to-digital converters; see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_approximation_ADC.

Comment: @Oli yes this is what I found out as well. One thing that I found was to use unix time stamps the time.h contains functions that I could use to make RTC timestamp into unix timestamps and then use seconds to find out if something is supposed to happen. I will update accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a similar system and implemented it as [described by Oli Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139206/manage-recurring-events-in-a-schedule-c/4139338#4139338). I had a table with the schedule. At power on a created a list of all the next events with a pointer to the original table entry and sorted them so that I only need to check the first entry in the table (Later I used a RTC that can cause an interrupt at a specific time). When an event got triggered I checked it the user entry can be removed or need to stay in the table and the event rescheduled.